# Merging multiple images into one single image based on overlapping

Tags: c#

I have 6 images
 Each image is part of a 180 degree (or so) panorama.  The images overlap.  The task is to write a program in C# that will import the images, determine where the images overlap and merge the images together to form a single image.

Write the program in such a way that the user can import as many images as he or she would like to have merged into one image.
There should be some function in the program that will determine if given 2 images the 2 images overlap and to what amount.
Also, the input images may not necessarily be constructed from a  strict linear axis of revolution, and their orientation may not be the same (you will need to consider rotation and both X and Y offsets to the overlap region as part of the program).

Comment: That seems really a (big) homework project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a large project. You might want to take a look at the source code for [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) for inspiration. Unless you're really set on doing it yourself, you might just want to use (and possibly contribute improvements) to Hugin instead of starting over.

OTOH, Hugin isn't written in C#, so if that's a requirement, you probably will have to start over. Offhand I don't remember if the source to Autopano-SIFT is available, but if so it would be a good start (it already handles one of the most complex parts of the task).

Comment: C# is requirement ..Thanks anyways Jerry.. I will look into it :)